# How to Handle Non-Multinormality in the Context of Exploratory Factor Analysis for Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, factor-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm trying to follow the book *A Step-by-Step Guide to Exploratory Factor Analysis with R and Rstudio*, by Marley W. Watkins, and apply the principles in the book to a real-world data set. Ultimately, my goal is to perform a logistic regression, but my variables are highly correlated; so although the model performs well, the coefficients are not easily interpreted. Interpretability is crucial to this project, hence the EFA. My data set has $13$ variables with $4452$ observations each. I have performed transformations $(x_{\text{new}}=\ln(x-\min(x)+1))$ on each variable so that they are each roughly normal. At least, skew and kurtosis are under control. However, the `mardia` test from R's `psych` package yields a multinormal distribution skewness of $26.64$ and kurtosis of $237.03$. These are insanely out-of-bounds for being able to conclude that the joint distribution is multinormal, since the current consensus is a maximum of $2$ for skew and $7$ for kurtosis. The EFA assumptions require multinormality in order to be valid. Unfortunately, the book is a bit short (read that - completely silent) on remedies for fixing non-multinormality.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: The predictors do not need to be normally distributed. Does your book recommend this?

Comment: Well, the book does say that if variables are not identically distributed, then the correlation coefficient is artificially restricted. So it recommends transforming to get reasonably normal distributions whenever possible. In addition, during the EFA, something can pop up as an artifact of the distribution instead of as a genuine factor.

Comment: I am confused. If you want to analyze your data and use it in logistic regression, then any result *should* be "an artifact of the distribution", isn't that the whole point? But then again, I am absolutely no expert in EFA.

Comment: Here's the quote from the book: "For example, it has long been
known that dichotomous items that are skewed in opposite directions may
produce what are known as difficulty factors when submitted to EFA (Bernstein
& Teng, 1989; Greer et al., 2006). That is, a factor may appear that is an artifact of variable distributions rather than the effect of their content." Does that answer your question?

Comment: Honestly, no, it doesn't... anyway, if we start out with dichotomous items, *no* transformation will make them "normal", short of replacing them by normal random variables, so I don't quite know how all this relates to some requirement of having normally distributed data for EFA. But again, I am no expert in EFA, just confused.

Comment: Heh. Well, I'm obviously not the expert, either! I don't have any deeper understanding to explain it better. What the quote says, apparently, is that two variables skewed in opposite directions can produce a fake factor in the EFA process. The papers cited are Bernstein, I. H., & Teng, G. (1989). Factoring items and factoring scales are different:
Spurious evidence for multidimensionality due to item categorization. Psychological
Bulletin, 105(3), 467–477. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.105.3.467.

Comment: and Greer, T., Dunlap, W. P., Hunter, S. T., & Berman, M. E. (2006). Skew and internal
consistency. Journal of Applied Psychology, 91(6), 1351–1358. https://doi.org/10.1037/
0021-9010.91.6.1351.

Comment: Bottom line here is that no transformation of binary or dichotomous variables will help anything that is otherwise regarded as a problem, whether rightly or wrongly. At most, exchanging high or low values will flip the signs of correlations.

Comment: Should I just abandon EFA for this case, then? It's not looking as though it's going to work, given that I see no way to make the assumptions valid.

Comment: My advice is that if you want to do logistic regression, then do logistic regression. I'd rather select predictors on e.g. scientific grounds than have EFA do it for me, or produce new predictors that are often harder to interpret than the original variables.